# Parametrize with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm learning selenium these days.

Can someone tell me how to parametrize a web application for testing in selenium?

Comment: Can you add more to your question, I don't understand what you are after. Would you like to create Data-Driven Selenium Tests?

Comment: yes.need to Create data driven selenium test.please send me a link / e-book to study more about selenium (except selenium.org) written for beginners.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java, you can create a `.java` file to store the variables with their locators and refer to those as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're looking for but in case you're trying to parametrize your tests for easy changes, you should take a look at Selenese variables:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#store-commands-and-selenium-variables

Comment: you've got a bad link. What were you trying to post?

Answer (score 0):

This extension provides a little more help with script parametrization in Selenium IDE: [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/)

It provides scoped variables, and can take parameters from an external XML file.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a test core with [Selenium's webdriver framework](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/). It's available in most of the popular languages: Java, Python, Ruby, C#.
Then the test core reads from our own format CSV file to perform the actions that has been generalized based on target web application, example:

1. action to click "go" button
2. action to add item to cart
3. action to select item with the name "abc"
4. etc etc

And then it will produce a log file for test report.

Is this what you mean by parametrize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java reflection API for parametrization also i am using open office excel sheet to pass parameter to selenium functions
Using Java reflection API you will be able to pass selenium functions as a string 
Selenium functions can be stored in a xml file and using java reflection API you can execute them

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest TestNG for this. As it easy to use dataProvider concept...

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to parametrize the selenium RC code. You can use CSV, Microsoft Excel, XML and the .properties file. In Microsoft Excel you can use POI APIs-HSSF(for Excel 2003)
and XSSF(for Excel 2007).

The best method that I find is using properties file. As told earlier also you can also use TestNG data provider but if you are using JUnit you have to use above mentioned method.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If your just using the Selenium IDE, [making parametrized tests](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/datadriven) is doable but kind of tricky.

I recommend exporting your scripts to a real programming language(if you haven't already) and using a testing framework to make you tests parametrized and data-driven.  Junit and TestNG both have good support for doing this.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: the ide really should be avoided if you're serious about test automation. It has some pretty severe limitations and the scripts will be prone to break